# AnyLogic running a model with random variables several times

Tags: variables, graph, model, anylogic

If you run the same model 10 consecutive times in AnyLogic, inorder to plot graphs. You will see at the bottom of the screen "Run: 10". Does that mean that the graph on Run:10 is averaging the values with the 9 previous Runs? Or is it just creating a new random graph each time I press run?

Thank you for your help

Comment: It depends on what you're plotting in the graph. You could do the both. But if you create new datasets for each run, the plot will display only the results of that specific run.

Comment: I want to run the same graph several times since my results are random. I want to average them over several runs. But what I am getting is a new graph without taking into consideration the results of the previous run. What should I do to get the results from previous runs averaged with the new run?
P.S. I am running the model simultaneously several times.

Answer (score 0):

If your runs come in succession (first run 0, then run 1 when run 0 finishes and so on...) you can save the results of each run in your Simulation Experiment and, eventually, plot the average values.

You can store your data (the output of each run) in a StatisticsDiscrete object (which easily return statistics like min, max, mean, stDev etc...), in a DataSet, in a Collection or everything else that suits your requirements.